# How to add custom affiliations as per my Organisation's name in nodesdk for hyperledger fabric?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I have created a Fabric network with 2 Organizations namely orgind, orgusa. In the nodesdk code for registeruser.js from fabric-samples/fabcar, their's a object in which you need to mention the user's affiliation. On using custom name like `'ordind.dep1'`, it returns an error `"message":"Failed to get Affiliation: sql: no rows in result set"`.

Fabric by default provides 3 organizations: org{1,2,3} with some departments.

How do I add my custom affiliation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Affiliation Service](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/master/AffiliationService.html) to see what affiliations you already have `getAll`, or use `create` to create new affiliations.